# can't open bitlocker encrypted devices with a clear key with cryptsetup but it works with dislocker

Tags: windows, encryption, ntfs, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

I'm trying to open a bitlocker encryptet partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p2`) with cryptsetup, but it always returns the following error:

```
# cryptsetup -v open --type bitlk /dev/nvme0n1p2 crypt0
Enter passphrase for /dev/nvme0n1p2:
Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).
```

The partition uses a clear encryption key and it works with dislocker

```
# dislocker -v /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt
# ls -lh /mnt
total 0
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 94G Jan  1  1970 dislocker-file
```

```
# cryptsetup -v bitlkDump /dev/nvme0n1p2
Info for BITLK device /dev/nvme0n1p2.
Version:        2
GUID:           xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Sector size:    512 [bytes]
Created:        Sun Jan 19 17:59:34 2020
Description:    (null)
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Cipher key:     128 bits

Keyslots:
 0: VMK
    GUID:           xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    Protection:     VMK protected with clear key
    Salt:           00000000000000000000000000000000
    Key data size:  44 [bytes]
 1: FVEK
    Key data size:  44 [bytes]

Metadata segments:
 0: FVE metadata area
    Offset:     49283072 [bytes]
    Size:       65536 [bytes]
 1: FVE metadata area
    Offset:     1635188736 [bytes]
    Size:       65536 [bytes]
 2: FVE metadata area
    Offset:     3319005184 [bytes]
    Size:       65536 [bytes]
 3: Volume header
    Offset:     111169536 [bytes]
    Size:       8192 [bytes]
    Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
Command successful.
```

(I removed the GUIDs)

Versions:

```
# cryptsetup -v --version
cryptsetup 2.3.4
```

```
# dislocker -vh
dislocker by Romain Coltel, v0.7.1 (compiled for Linux/x86_64)
Compiled version: master:dcc08b5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cryptsetup currently doesn't support unlocking BitLocker devices with a clear key. So you'll need to use dislocker with this device. There is unfortunately still a lot of BitLocker features we don't support in cryptsetup.

Feel free to report an RFE issue on [cryptsetup GitLab](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup).

(Btw. It's weird, it doesn't show the correct error message, it should say: `Activation of partially decrypted BITLK device is not supported.` I should spend less time here and more time fixing bugs :-)

Comment: by clear key, do you mean the default secret key of all zeros?